# How can I get scons to use Clang with libc++?

Tags: c++, clang, scons, clang++, libc++

How can I get scons to use Clang with libc++? Putting "-stdlib=libc++" in any of the flags I pass to the Environment results in undefined reference errors like the following:

```
hello.o: In function `main':
hello.cpp:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `std::__1::cout'
hello.o: In function `std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)':
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option to select libc++ needs to be both in the compiler and the linker flags:

```
env = Environment(CXX = 'clang++',
                  CXXFLAGS = '-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++',
                  LINKFLAGS = '-stdlib=libc++')

env.Program('hello.cpp')
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, scons still trying to use visual studio commands for the link step, also, scons is injecting '/nologo' in CCFLAGS